# filebeat unable to monitor containers application log path

Tags: kubernetes, containers, filebeat

I want to monitor the containers logs using filebeat kubernetes deplyment and the log format is in json format it is just monitoring the logs from containers but not this json file saved inside the container

So far i have enabled filebeat deployment following link
Run Filebeat on Kubernetes | Filebeat Reference [8.7] | Elastic

But it is not monitoring the application log path configured via ecs logging by springboot container:

Following are the log path from container

root@service-consumer-5b4c5f65bd-9qhf9:/# ls /logs/
**ECS-consumer.log **
ECS-consumer.log.json

Need to understand how I can monitor this json & log files using filebeat kubernetes deployment.

Regards
Pratiksha

Comment: pleas find below filebeat.yml configuration which we are trying to use for log containers log monitoring